# MYSQL Update statement - unknown column

Tags: mysql, join

I have  a select query which works correctly with the below output:

[image]

I would like to create an update statement to set the value of the despgoods_alldetails.loadid column = loaddetails.loadid where despgoods_alldetails_despgoodsid=loaddetails.despgoodsid.loadid.

I was thinking along the lines of

> update despgoods_alldetails 
>   set despgoods_alldetails.loadid = loaddetails.loadid 
>   where despgoods_alldetails.despgoodsid=loaddetails.despgoodsid

This query fails with the below error:
[image]

any idea how I can get this update statement to work?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost had it, you just need a reference to the second table.

```
UPDATE despgoods_alldetails, loaddetails
    SET despgoods_alldetails.loadid = loaddetails.loadid
    WHERE despgoods_alldetails.despgoodsid=loaddetails.despgoodsid
```

Comment: Update statements cannot update more than one table (at least not in any implementation I've worked with)

Comment: @Mac They can in MySQL. See the [UPDATE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: I stand corrected. Check that out. A subquery is more portable, though.

Comment: Thanks Joe, works perfectly. @Mac syntax also works 100%. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

`loaddetails` is a separate table from the one you are trying to update. This can't be done directly in a SQL update. You'll need a subselect like this instead:

```
update despgoods_alldetails
set despgoods_alldetails.loadid = (
    select loaddetails.loadid
    from loaddetails
    where despgoods_alldetails.despgoodsid=loaddetails.despgoodsid
)
```

Comment: Hi @Mac, thanks for the prompt response. by subselect do I have to embed my select statement in my update statement? any chance you can elaborate a little further for me or provide a sample query? Thanks, R

Comment: @RyanSmith Just did. This is called a "correlated subquery" because it references a column from the outer statement.

Comment: Thanks Mac, worked perfectly. @Joe Stefanelli syntax also 100%. Thanks again, apreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put two tables after update clause like this

```
update despgoods_alldetails, loaddetails set despgoods_alldetails.loadid =     loaddetails.loadid where despgoods_alldetails.despgoodsid=loaddetails.despgoodsid
```

Can you found one simple example in this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update  
  despgoods_alldetails as da
join 
  loaddetails as l
using 
  (despgoodsid)
set 
  da.loadid = l.loadid;
```